# Why am I seeing a huge red line after open quotes in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch, sublime-text-3

I copy-pasted a batch file script from [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/872137/323079) into Sublime Text 3, and had the following red line appear:

[image]

After some research and experimentation, this behaviour seems to be triggered by open quotes. Adding a `"` to the end of Line 6 gets rid of the red line, and adding a `"` on a separate line elsewhere in the script triggers another red line immediately after it, confirming this.

However, this still leaves two issues.

1. I've been writing batch files in Sublime for a long time with this setup, so why has this behaviour only now surfaced - **and how can I get rid of it?**
2. I can see no open quotes on Line 6 that could have triggered the red line. Have I missed something, or is this a glitch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime thinks the caret (`^`) is escaping the quotation marks next to it, so the line thinks you're short a matching ".

Note the slightly different colour in my editor:

[image]

Add `& REM "` to the end of the line, and it'll go away. FINDSTR doesn't use it as an escape, but other commands do.

Comment: I knew it was going to be something to do wth escape sequences. Thanks Silas. Also, unrelated, but can I ask how you were able to get such a high quality screenshot of code up close? Whenever I try I get a severely pixelated version.

Comment: Not that you care anymore, but for historical record; I just pumped up my font size to a ridiculous number.

Comment: I appreciate you weighing in, it’s a useful trick to know.